# Detect the input range when typing ontop of selection?

Tags: javascript, html

So I have a textarea in my html called `code`. Here is my sample:

```js
document.getElementById("code").addEventListener("input", function(ev) {
  console.log(this.selectionStart),
  console.log(this.selectionEnd),
  console.log(ev.data)
})
```

```html
<textarea id="code"></textarea>
```

When I've selected the whole text like this:

[image]

And I type `a` - I get:

```
1
1
a
```

Instead of like:

```
1
9
a
```

I believe this is because it's first deleting the selected text and after that sending the input event on a blank textbox - any ideas how to get around this?

I'm trying to detect changes into the input so I can submit them to my server since I'm trying to implement live code sharing capability.

Comment: This sounds like [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What do you actually need to achieve?

Comment: Race condition? Same on every browser?

Comment: @PM77-1 I'm trying to detect changes into the input so I can submit them to my server since I'm trying to implement live code sharing capability.

Comment: @Mruf Tested on latest version of Chrome on Windows.

Comment: Yes! when input event gets called the selected text was already deleted. If you want to know the previous `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` you must save them in another variable outside the eventListener, so next time you could have previous selection boundaries.

Comment: @CristianTorres But how do I distinguish of when it's actually the selected text being replaced or the user is genuinely typing a single character.

Comment: Handle the `select` event and set a variable to the value of the textarea. When the `input` event occurs, and value is different, you know it was a replacement.

Comment: @HereticMonkey What about if I just want to type a character without selecting anything first.

Comment: The event is always going to fire after the change is made. It won't fire if you just select the text.

Comment: ...Then you wouldn't have the problem outlined in the question?

Comment: @HereticMonkey Yeah but I want to both allow normal typing without selection and also selection typing. You know what - I guess it would be best if you just post your solution as an answer.

Comment: So, store the value of the textarea in the `input` event too.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement something like:

```js
var oldSelection = {start: 0, end: 0};

with(document.getElementById("code")) {
  addEventListener('mouseup', function(ev) {
    oldSelection.start = this.selectionStart; 
    oldSelection.end = this.selectionEnd;
    console.log(oldSelection);
  })
  addEventListener("input", function(ev) {
    console.log(oldSelection); console.log(ev.data);
  })
}
```

```html
<textarea id="code"></textarea>
```

This way when input event occurs you know which range was selected before.

Footnote: you should implement it in a plugin's way so you can attach this behaviour to more than one input.

Comment: I've found a bug - if you continuously type a single character the start and end position will stay the same.

Comment: Yes, until you make a selection again with the mouse. It's not perfect but it gives you an idea, right?

Comment: It does I used `select` event to make a working solution on my own.